# How to move images in particular path in cocoa 2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I am new to cocoa 2d  I am trying to develop  move multiple images in a particular path and insert another image in the middle of this path images similar like "ZUMA REVANGE GAME" .In this game how images moving in exact path and insert image in the middle. can any one tell me how they implemented.

Thank very much.

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to cocos2d I suggest you look [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials) (In section "Beginning Game Programming with Cocos2D")

Answer (score 0):

search on bezier path.

```
   ccBezierConfig bezier;
   bezier.controlPoint_1 = ccp(0, s.height/2);
   bezier.controlPoint_2 = ccp(300, -s.height/2);
   bezier.endPosition = ccp(300,100);

   id bezierForward = [CCBezierBy actionWithDuration:3 bezier:bezier];
```